# Eclipse Continuation Indent

Tags: eclipse, indentation

Is there a way to configure the indentation eclipse uses for manual line breaks? It indents by 8 spaces no matter what I do.

I get this:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG =
        org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(myClassname.class);
```

when I'd like it to give me this:

```
private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG =
    org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(myClassname.class);
```

Eclipse's line wrapping can be configured to give me the correct result when the line is too long, but I'd like to be able to get less indentation even if the line break is manual.

Comment: Did you try configuring indentation settings?

Comment: I've been looking around there for quite a while and still haven't found the knob I'm looking for. Even with indentation and tab sizes at 2 it indents by 8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Eclipse Juno

- open the preferences dialog (Window > Preferences).
- go to the preference page Java > Code Style > Formatter.
- press the Edit... button (for the Active profile).
- if it is the default one from Eclipse (Eclipse [built-in]), you need to give it a new name.
- click on the Line Wrapping tab
- set the value to 1 for "Default indentation for wrapped lines" (by default it is 2)

(check the Identation tab and check what the indentation size is set at, by default it should be 4)

Comment: Even after doing that and restarting eclipse it still indents by 8. In the indentation tab I'm using spaces only with indentation size and tab size 2. Restoring the defaults and changing only the default indentation for wrapped lines also didn't work. I'm running Juno Service Release 2. Does that fix work for you with the example I gave?

Comment: Yes, it works for me just changing the "Default indentation for wrapped lines" setting. I'm on Juno, but not sure if SR1 or SR2 (not at my dev machine at the moment)